# How to perform a multi-row multi-column operation in parallel within PySpark, with minimum loops?

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I would like to perform a multi-row multi-column operation in Pyspark with less or no loops.
Spark 'df' has following data

```
city    time    temp    humid
NewYork 1500    67      57
NewYork 1600    69      55
NewYork 1700    70      56
Dallas  1500    47      37
Dallas  1600    49      35
Dallas  1700    50      39
```

I used 'For' loops but at the cost of parallelism and its not effective.

```
city_list = [i.city for i in df.select('city').distinct().collect()]
metric_cols = ['temp', 'humid']
for city in city_list:
    for metric in metric_cols:
        tempDF = df.filter(col("city") == city)
        metric_values = [(i[metric]) for i in tempDF.select(metric).collect()]
        time_values = [(i['time']) for i in tempDF.select('time').collect()]
        tuples = list(zip(time_values, metric_values))
        newColName = city + metric
        df = df.withColumn(newColName, lit(tuples))
```

I dont think its working either.

I expect the output to be

```
city    time  temp  humid timetemp                         timehumidity
NewYork 1500  67    57    [(1500,67),(1600,69),(1700,70)] [(1500,57),(1600,55),(1700,56)]
NewYork 1600  69    55    [(1500,67),(1600,69),(1700,70)] [(1500,57),(1600,55),(1700,56)]
NewYork 1700  70    56    [(1500,67),(1600,69),(1700,70)] [(1500,57),(1600,55),(1700,56)]
Dallas  1500  47    37    [(1500,47),(1600,49),(1700,50)] [(1500,37),(1600,35),(1700,39)]
Dallas  1600  49    35    [(1500,47),(1600,49),(1700,50)] [(1500,37),(1600,35),(1700,39)]
Dallas  1700  50    39    [(1500,47),(1600,49),(1700,50)] [(1500,37),(1600,35),(1700,39)]
```

or at the least

```
city     timetemp                         timehumidity
NewYork  [(1500,67),(1600,69),(1700,70)]  [(1500,57),(1600,55),(1700,56)]
Dallas   [(1500,47),(1600,49),(1700,50)]  [(1500,37),(1600,35),(1700,39)]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution with higher performance in PySpark

```
def create_tuples(df):
    mycols = ("temp","humid")
    lcols = mcols.copy()
    lcols.append("time")
    for lcol in lcols:
        df = df.select("*",collect_list(lcol).over(Window.partitionBy("city")).alias(lcol+'_list'))
    for mycol in mycols:
        df = df.withColumn(mycol+'_tuple', arrays_zip("time_list", mycol+'_list'))
    return df
tuples_df = create_tuples(df)
```

Answer (score 2):

One option is to use `struct` function:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
df.groupby('city').agg(F.collect_list(F.struct(F.col('time'),F.col('temp'))).alias('timetemp'), F.collect_list(F.struct(F.col('time'),F.col('humid'))).alias('timehumidity')).show(2, False)
```

Output:

```
+-------+------------------------------------+------------------------------------+
|city   |timetemp                            |timehumidity                        |
+-------+------------------------------------+------------------------------------+
|Dallas |[[1500, 47], [1600, 49], [1700, 50]]|[[1500, 37], [1600, 35], [1700, 39]]|
|NewYork|[[1500, 67], [1600, 69], [1700, 70]]|[[1500, 57], [1600, 55], [1700, 56]]|
+-------+------------------------------------+------------------------------------+
```

You can join it with you original dataframe.
If you want to have the results as tuples, then you might need to write your own `udf`.

---

You also can define lists of columns and handle more column sets:

```
list_1 = ['time']
list_2 = ['temp', 'humid'] #change these accordingly

df_array = [df.groupby('city').agg((F.collect_list(F.struct(F.col(x),F.col(y)))).alias(x+y)) for x in list_1 for y in list_2]
for df_temp in df_array:
    df = df.join(df_temp, on='city', how='left')
df.show()
```

Output:

```
+-------+----+----+-----+------------------------------------+------------------------------------+
|city   |time|temp|humid|timetemp                            |timehumid                           |
+-------+----+----+-----+------------------------------------+------------------------------------+
|Dallas |1500|47  |37   |[[1500, 47], [1600, 49], [1700, 50]]|[[1500, 37], [1600, 35], [1700, 39]]|
|Dallas |1600|49  |35   |[[1500, 47], [1600, 49], [1700, 50]]|[[1500, 37], [1600, 35], [1700, 39]]|
|Dallas |1700|50  |39   |[[1500, 47], [1600, 49], [1700, 50]]|[[1500, 37], [1600, 35], [1700, 39]]|
|NewYork|1500|67  |57   |[[1500, 67], [1600, 69], [1700, 70]]|[[1500, 57], [1600, 55], [1700, 56]]|
|NewYork|1600|69  |55   |[[1500, 67], [1600, 69], [1700, 70]]|[[1500, 57], [1600, 55], [1700, 56]]|
|NewYork|1700|70  |56   |[[1500, 67], [1600, 69], [1700, 70]]|[[1500, 57], [1600, 55], [1700, 56]]|
+-------+----+----+-----+------------------------------------+------------------------------------+
```

Comment: This will work except that the columns 'time' and 'humidity' are just examples, there are 50 more columns and therefore cannot hardcode the new columns.

Comment: check the answer now.

Comment: This works, but performance is slow. Accepted the answer. Thanks